# No matching declaration found after argument-dependent lookup. _safeMint(msg.sender, supply.increment());

Tags: web3js, remix, nft

[image]

I need help im new and can figure out what is wrong

Comment: Can you include all your smart contract code?

Answer (score 0):

The increment() function does not return a value. This can be seen from the Counters class (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.5.0/contracts/utils/Counters.sol)

Make code like this:

```
_tokenIdCounter.increment();
uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
_safeMint(before, tokenId);
```